Booting into initramfs
Start computer and it only loads to a initramfs prompt. Tried reboot -f and i get to a boot screen with advanced options for ubuntu, memory test, and uefi firmware settings. I tried the advanced options one and then a recovery mode option. Then a huge wall of text blew by and at the end I’m back at the initramfs prompt. And shoot it there is an alert that uuid=808b3b81-9c8c-449c-325856347d71 does not exist. Creeping into shell.

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used. Also what is the last thing you did before this issue happened?

O yes it’s the latest LTS 24.04

In initramfs prompt try this : fsck /dev/sdaX -f. (sdaX : replace X by number of your root partition)
